# Paint method execute many times

Tags: java, swing

Why this ***paint*** function execute many times while I run my code?

I am trying to run this code only one time, but it execute many times, and I don't know why it does that!

```
public class DrawFrame extends JFrame {

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    System.out.println("hello Frame");
}
}
```

---

```
public class NJFrame {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    DrawFrame NJFrame = new DrawFrame();
    NJFrame.setSize(1000, 1000);
    NJFrame.setVisible(true);
    NJFrame.setLocation(400, 150);
    NJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your code manipulates the JFrame a number of times:

```
DrawFrame NJFrame = new DrawFrame(); // (1) Create the frame
NJFrame.setSize(1000, 1000);         // (2) Resize the frame
NJFrame.setVisible(true);            // (3) Show the frame
NJFrame.setLocation(400, 150);       // (4) Move the frame
```

It would seem that each of these operations causes a paint event to be fired, which your `paint` method handles.

Comment: Yes it's from` NJFrame.setSize(1000, 1000); `

Comment: Then how can i make it execute only one time

Comment: You cannot do that, since each time you manipulate the frame it will fire a repaint event. Unless you are facing many, many of these events, this should not be an issue. I may misunderstand your concern, however.

Answer (score 2):

`paint` method is automatically called whenever it is needed. It's handled by Swing and is invoked when the content pane of your frame needs to be repainted, when the window size is resized, minimized and so on.

For more information, you can [explore](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) it.